# MINSIGSTKSZ error after update in my manjaro linux

Tags: c++

After I update my system with

```
sudo pacman -Syu
```

I can’t run my college coursework and get this error

```
> make                                                                                
g++ -c -Wall -Wpedantic -Werror -Wextra -std=c++14  main_test.cpp
In file included from /usr/include/signal.h:328,
                 from catch.hpp:8034,
                 from main_test.cpp:2:
catch.hpp:10822:58: error: call to non-‘constexpr’ function ‘long int sysconf(int)’
10822 |     static constexpr std::size_t sigStackSize = 32768 >= MINSIGSTKSZ ? 32768 : MINSIGSTKSZ;
      |                                                          ^~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/bits/sigstksz.h:24,
                 from /usr/include/signal.h:328,
                 from catch.hpp:8034,
                 from main_test.cpp:2:
/usr/include/unistd.h:640:17: note: ‘long int sysconf(int)’ declared here
  640 | extern long int sysconf (int __name) __THROW;
      |                 ^~~~~~~
In file included from main_test.cpp:2:
catch.hpp:10881:45: error: size of array ‘altStackMem’ is not an integral constant-expression
10881 |     char FatalConditionHandler::altStackMem[sigStackSize] = {};
      |                                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~
make: *** [makefile:33: main_test.o] Error 1
```

before I update the system, it’s run well without an error
How I can fix this? I really need to fix this for my coursework

Comment: `pacman -S syu` this installs package syu, to update system use `pacman -Suy`

Comment: Ohh sorry im typo

Comment: @ToosakaRin Show your `main_test.cpp` code. Did you anywhere use a non const to define an array size?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/sLHHxJ4b
Here my '''main_test.cpp''' , it my coursework

Comment: what is catch.hpp? Please post an [MCVE]

Comment: @KamilCuk A header from the Catch2 unit testing framework.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Suprisingly https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=NEWS;h=85e84fe53699fe9e392edffa993612ce08b2954a;hb=HEAD :

> Add _SC_MINSIGSTKSZ and _SC_SIGSTKSZ.
> When _SC_SIGSTKSZ_SOURCE or  _GNU_SOURCE are defined, MINSIGSTKSZ and SIGSTKSZ are no longer constant on Linux.  MINSIGSTKSZ is redefined to sysconf(_SC_MINSIGSTKSZ) and SIGSTKSZ is redefined to sysconf (_SC_SIGSTKSZ).

I fear this change will bite many programs. This is odd, because in POSIX `MINSIGSTKSZ` is a constant. It is a big change.

> How I can fix this?

You can:

- downgrade your system to previous glibc or use a system with previous glibc
- or add something like the following before the definition of `sigStackSize`:

  ```
    #undef MINSIGSTKSZ
    #define MINSIGSTKSZ 16384
  ```
- or fix `catch.hpp` so that it doesn't assume that `MINSIGSTKSZ` is a constant expression, and instead `malloc`s the alternate stack
- or compile without `_GNU_SOURCE` and without `_SC_SIGSTKSZ_SOURCE` macros.

Comment: Thanks ,  I add '#undef MINSIGSTKSZ
  #define MINSIGSTKSZ 16384' and it's work